# ReflectionException - Class name does not exist in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, seeding

I have a little problem trying to seed my comments table.
I'm 100% sure that I **have** the Class `CommentTableSeeder.php` in my `/database/seeds` directory.

---

**CommentTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CommentTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('comments')->delete();

        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => 'Chris Sevilleja',
            'text' => 'Look I am a test comment.'
        ));

        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => 'Nick Cerminara',
            'text' => 'This is going to be super crazy.'
        ));

        Comment::create(array(
            'author' => 'Holly Lloyd',
            'text' => 'I am a master of Laravel and Angular.'
        ));
    }

}
```

---

Then when I run : `php artisan db:seed`

I kept getting

[image]

I've also try running `composer update` and run : `php artisan db:seed` - still get the same result.

Any hints / help will be much appreciated !

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` before trying this?

Comment: Not yet, ok. I'll do it now.

Comment: Working now. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: No problem, going to add it as an answer for completions sake.

Comment: Sure. go for it. I'll make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to fix this error. What this does, among other things, is refreshes the list of classes available to your application.

In this case, while the class did exist in the right location, it was unavailable in your autoloaded class list, and thus returning a `Not Found` error.